# How to check if youtube url in C#

Tags: c#

I want to check if an given URL a is link to `http://youtube.com`.

I know there are lots of various shortened version's of the links (e.g. `http://youtu.be`), so what I am after is a way to resolve the URL and see if it ends up as `http://youtube.com`.

A couple of example inputs are:

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/[videoid]
http://www.youtu.be/watch?v=[videoid]
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: What happens when Youtube add a new link format, nothing will stop them doing that in the future.

Comment: But they are not going to change their domain id. Is that possible to check if the url is from youtube?

Comment: So you want to know if a given URL will resolve to youtube.com?

Comment: Thank DaveShaw, you have change it to match my issue.

Comment: No problems. It's nice to see a question saved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could perform a `HEAD` request:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.youtu.be/Ddn4MGaS3N4");
request.Method = "HEAD";
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) {
    Console.WriteLine("Does this resolve to youtube?: {0}", response.ResponseUri.ToString().Contains("youtube.com") ? "Yes" : "No");
}
```

Appears to work fine. Unsure of edge cases but seems to do the job.

(**Note**: No error checking here such as 404 errors, etc).

Comment: Yeah, it work very well. I have add a try catch to prevent error.

'private bool IsYoutubeLink(string item)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(item);
            request.Method = "HEAD";
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                return response.ResponseUri.ToString().Contains("youtube.com") ? true : false;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }'

Answer (score 2):

```
                    bool isYoutube = false;

                    string host = new Uri(url).Host;
                    if (host == "youtube.com" || host == "youtu.be")
                    {
                        isYoutube = true;
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First you may have to check what the hostname is for youtube (I'm just assuming it is http://youtube.com) but after you have that the following code will do what you want;

```
 using System.Net;

 IPHostEntry host = Dns.Resolve(theInputHostName);
 if (host.HostName == "http://youtube.com")
      // it resolves to youtube, do something.
```

Comment: This crashes (just tried it..). It appears to be some sort of DNS resolution issue for `youtu.be`. In fact, it fails for `youtube.com` as well.

Comment: I end up writing a function base on your code: the first parameter is item, and it is an youtube url ('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGes6_ypp28')

`private bool IsYoutubeLink(string item)
    {
        IPHostEntry host = Dns.Resolve(item);
        if (host.HostName == "http://youtube.com")
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }`

It generate an error message: **SocketException was unhandled by user code**
The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether a given URL redirects (using status codes `301`/`302`) to an YouTube URL, you may either use `WebClient`/`HttWebRequest`/whatever directly and check the response, or disable `HttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect` and traverse all redirects manually (checking the status code and then the `Location` HTTP header).